# Rails Delayed job start time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Is it possible to give a time argument for delayed job to start a particular time instead of giving the interval.?

I want to be able to do

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(ScheduleJob.new(args),0,:run_at => Some valid time format)
```

but I am only able to do

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(ScheduleJob.new(args),0,:run_at => Proc.new{15.minutes.from_now})
```

I tried giving a datetime object but it fails to enqueue the job.

Answer (score 0):

[Based on this](http://zadasnotes.blogspot.com/2011/03/rails-tips-using-delayedjob-to-schedule.html) you would need to create a custom "method that calculates when to send the reminder based on the meeting time" or in your case whatever the date/time is. For instance if you wanted to send it at midnight you would want the custom method to return the number of minutes from that point until midnight.